# Empotrando un video de Youtube en mi app Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy integrando un vídeo de Youtube en un app Android. Tras leer varios blogs, otros posts... estoy un poco perdido con el error que tengo. El layout que estoy pintando es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
    tools:context=".UD1">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubePlayerView"
        android:layout_width="715dp"
        android:layout_height="461dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Por otro lado, la Activity que he creado:

```
public class UD1 extends YouTubeBaseActivity {
    String APIkey = "aavvss";
    String video1 = "hjFaqDNUVFo";
    String video2 = "41cJ0mqWses";
    String video3 = "uT8-YdXPNBk";
    String video4 = "vSdAv931s-g";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ud1);
        final YouTubePlayerView youtubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtubePlayerView);
        playVideo(video1, youtubePlayerView);

    }

    public void playVideo(final String videoId, YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView) {
        //initialize youtube player view
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(APIkey,new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                    YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId);
                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                    YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                }
            });
}
```

}

Sin embargo, cuando corro la aplicación, el error que obtengo es el siguiente:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.

Full stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: es.elena.learninggame, PID: 8501
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.elena.learninggame/es.elena.learninggame.UD1}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in es.elena.learninggame:layout/ud1: Binary XML file line #11 in es.elena.learninggame:layout/ud1: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in es.elena.learninggame:layout/ud1: Binary XML file line #11 in es.elena.learninggame:layout/ud1: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in es.elena.learninggame:layout/ud1: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:438)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:3326)
    at es.elena.learninggame.UD1.onCreate(UD1.java:28)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7783)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7772)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source:19)
```

E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.(Unknown Source:1)
            ... 28 more

Observando la app, mi Activity ya extiende **YouTubeBaseActivity**. Aunque, como dije antes he leído varios foros, posts antes de publicarlo aquí, no he conseguido dar con la solución. ¿Podría alguien, por favor, darme algún tipo de guía sobre lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias por adelantado

Comment: Como el error se indica en el .xml , elimina el tema : android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" y prueba nuevamente, esto es la causa, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can
>   only be created with an Activity which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as
>   its context.

indica que :

> Un YouTubePlayerView solo puede crearse con una Actividad que
>   extienda YouTubeBaseActivity como su contexto.

En este caso el problema es la inicialización, después de obtener la referencia de la vista, instancias usando la referencia de la `Activity` que extiende de `YouTubeBaseActivity` , usa `this` como contexto:

```
   YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
```

Aunque de la forma que lo realizas también es valida usando `OnInitializedListener()`:

```
 youTubePlayerView.initialize(APIkey,new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        });
```

Revisando el problema, este indica que el problema se genera en el layout:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in
>   es.elena.learninggame:layout/ud1: Binary XML file line #11 in
>   es.elena.learninggame:layout/ud1: Error inflating class
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView  Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in
>   es.elena.learninggame:layout/ud1: Error inflating class
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView  Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

**En este caso el problema se puede generar por el tema definido en `YouTubePlayerView`, elimina el tema y el problema será solucionado.**

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

---

Aquí puedes encontrar un [ejemplo funcional usando Youtube API](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Youtube-API).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Efectivamente, ha sido quitar el theme y ha funcionado!!! Muchas gracias de nuevo!!

Answer (score 0):

Tu clase debe extender de `YouTubeBaseActivity` e implementar `YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener` tu clase quedaria asi:

```
public class UD1 extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    YouTubePlayerView playerView;
    String APIkey = "aavvss";
    String video1 = "hjFaqDNUVFo";
    String video2 = "41cJ0mqWses";
    String video3 = "uT8-YdXPNBk";
    String video4 = "vSdAv931s-g";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ud1);
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.youtubePlayerView);
        playerView.initialize(API_KEY,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(video1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    }
}
```

El detalle es que siempre sera el video1 el que se muestre al crear la actividad, pero puedes pasar una lista de videos para que tengas la opcion de ir al siguiente de forma dinamica